# Get variable with all content outside a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to create a variable outside the foreach loop, containing all the content that it is getting inside the loop.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$fields = array();

foreach( $submit_fields as $key => $items ) {
   if( $items->value == true ) {
       $fields = " <div class='control-group'>
                <label>" . $items->label . "</label>
            <div class='controls'>
            <input type='text' class='form-control input-small' name='" . $items->name . "'>
     </div>";
   }
}

print_r( $fields );
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `$fields` to the following:

```
$fields[] = "
 <div class='control-group'>
 <label>" . $items->label . "</label>
 <div class='controls'>
 <input type='text' class='form-control input-small' name='" . $items->name . "'>
 </div>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Work as a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be

```
$fields = array();

foreach($submit_fields as $key => $items) {
if($items->value == true) {

$fields[] = "
     <div class='control-group'>
     <label>" . $items->label . "</label>
     <div class='controls'>
     <input type='text' class='form-control input-small' name='" . $items->name . "'>
     </div>";

    }
}

print_r($fields);
```

You can also associate your array with key values by changing 
$fields[]
to
$fields[$key]